# The count parameter in onTextChanged method of TextWatcher is not working properly for EditText with input type textWebPassword

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-inputtype

The count parameter in onTextChanged method of TextWatcher is not working properly for EditText with input type textWebPassword.
The code inside else if(count==1) is running even if there are more than 1 characters in EditText.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText ePassword;
private TextView tPassword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    tPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_password);
    ePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    ePassword.addTextChangedListener(textWatcherPassword);


}
private TextWatcher textWatcherPassword = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (count == 0) {
            // start fade out animation
            tPassword.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out));
            //Make the elements invisible
            tPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        else if(count==1){
            // Make fade in elements Visible first
            tPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // start fade in animation
            tPassword.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in));
        }
        Log.e("Count", count + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
}
```

Logcat output is(for password with more than 1 character):

```
08-19 16:54:49.465  25167-25167/com.test.example E/Count﹕ 1
08-19 16:54:49.607  25167-25167/com.test.example E/Count﹕ 1
08-19 16:54:49.756  25167-25167/com.test.example E/Count﹕ 1
08-19 16:54:49.881  25167-25167/com.test.example E/Count﹕ 1
08-19 16:54:50.006  25167-25167/com.test.example E/Count﹕ 1
08-19 16:54:50.122  25167-25167/com.test.example E/Count﹕ 1
```

Comment: use logcat to log exactly what you are receiving in `count`, then you will be able to know what's really happening.

Comment: After some research, I got my code running by using s.length()==1 instead of count==1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, I got my code running by using s.length()==1 instead of count==1.

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            // start fade out animation
            tPassword.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out));
            //Make the elements invisible
            tPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else if (s.length() == 1) {
            // Make fade in elements Visible first
            tPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // start fade in animation
            tPassword.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know it's an old question/answer, but count is this value because according to the TextWatcher documentation: "This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)). It is not the length of S, as you expected.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem while using the **onTextChanged** Method! 
The **count** indicator was always 1 regardless how long the word was which was inserted, and the **before** indicator was always 0. Check the logs:

```
01-01 03:15:35.440: E/OLE(22401): onTextChangedOLD word: start:0 before:0 count:0
01-01 03:15:39.380: E/OLE(22401): onTextChangedOLD word:S start:0 before:0 count:1
01-01 03:15:41.170: E/OLE(22401): onTextChangedOLD word:SE start:1 before:0 count:1
01-01 03:15:41.170: E/OLE(22401): onTextChangedOLD word:SEK start:2 before:0 count:1
...
```

Funny thing was that this happend on one android device (rockchip) while on another (samsung tab 2) it worked correctly. Both have the android version 4.2.2, while the problematic one was a specific android device of manufacturor rockchip.

I solved the problem using the methods **beforeTextChanged** and **afterTextChanged**.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {

Context context;
int startC, countC, beforeC, afterC;
CharSequence userInputC;

public CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.startC = 0;
    this.countC = 0;
    this.beforeC = 0;
    this.afterC = 0;
    this.userInputC = "";
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    countC = s.length();
    startC = countC;
    beforeC = countC; 
    afterC = countC;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence userInput, int start, int before, int count) {

    userInputC = userInput;
    afterC = countC++;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  

    ModActivity modActivity = ((ModActivity) context);

    //we only search if the user inserts more than 2 chars
    if(countC==2 && beforeC == 1){

        // query the database based on the user input
        modActivity.startDBSearch(userInputC.toString());
    }

}
```

Now the I could catch the correct occurrence of the before and count indicator. The new log output was as follows:

```
01-01 03:15:35.440: E/OLE(22401): onTextChanged word: start:0 before:0 count:1
01-01 03:15:39.380: E/OLE(22401): onTextChanged word:S start:0 before:0 count:1
01-01 03:15:41.170: E/OLE(22401): onTextChanged word:SE start:1 before:1 count:2
01-01 03:15:41.170: E/OLE(22401): onTextChanged word:SEK start:2 before:2 count:3
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But why this happening

Comment: May be one of them has custom OS over vanila android.